# "Code signing "GoogleToolboxForMac.framework" failed" when uploading to Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, app-store-connect

Everytime I try to upload a build to itunes connect I get this error. Otherwise project works well in simulator and on iphone. Any suggestions? I can upload logs, but they're very long. I've tried cleaning, restarting xcode, adding the specific reference to the linked libraries list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: That took a while. I solved it by moving all of my certificates from login to system. I'm not really sure how this helped exactly, but I do know that it fixed the problem.

Comment: How come this made it work? If you move from login to system, you wont see the certificate in XCode, atleast XCode 10 behaves like that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and same message (just happened with no warning and very little explanation while uploading the archive).
Moving certificates to system did not do it ... but in the process I had to re-issue a distribution certificate and that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had project configuration issue. I placed `x86_64` to `VALID_ARCHS` project setting and Carthage didn't strip simulator architecture. For some reason logs didn't contain any error and I had hard time investigating.

After I deleted `x86_64` from `VALID_ARCHS` it uploaded build without issues.